# Show that$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{f(i)}$ converges and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{f(i)} \le \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove following proposition

> **Proposition**. If $\{a_i\}$ is a sequence of **non-negative real numbers** and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i$ converges, then for arbitrary subsequence $\{a_{f(i)}\}$, $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{f(i)}$ will also converge. Also we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{f(i)} \le \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$$

**My attempt:**

Firstly, we will show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{f(i)}$ converges.

We know that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$ converges, hence $\{\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_i\}$ is bounded (say the bound is some $M >0$). Since (by definition of a subsequence) $f$ is an increasing map from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, we can conclude that $f(N) ≥ N$, $\forall N$. But that implies

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{f(i)} ≤ \sum_{i=0}^{f(N)}a_i ≤ M$$

Hence $\{\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{f(i)}\}$ is bounded, and it is also increasing (since all real numbers are non-negative in the sequence), thus $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{f(i)}$ must converge.

Now we prove the second part of the proposition. Once more, note that for all $N$, we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{f(i)} \le \sum_{i=0}^{f(N)}a_i$$

Both $\{\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{f(i)}\}$ and $\{\sum_{i=0}^{f(N)}a_i\}$ converge, hence we can let $N \rightarrow \infty$ to obtain

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{f(i)} ≤ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{f(N)}a_i$$

And since $\{\sum_{i=0}^{f(N)}a_i\}$ is a subsequence of $\{\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_i\}$, both sequences converge to the same value, and thus

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_{f(i)} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{f(i) }≤ \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{f(N)}a_i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i$$

as desired. $\Box$

---

**Is the proof correct?** If not, where is the mistake? And what is a correct proof?

Comment: I think you are right.